# In what ways can I force a session to end?

Tags: coldfusion

I want to force a session to end after 30 minutes regardless of activity. The first thing I thought of was this (untested):

```
function onApplicationStart() application.sessionLife = 30;

function onSessionStart() session.timeStarted = now();

function onRequestStart() {
    if ( dateDiff("n", session.timeStarted, now()) > application.sessionLife)
        structClear(session);
}
```

What other ways are available to force a session to end?

The obvious one is a session cookie that expires after 30 minutes. But I'm not sure if session cookies listen to the sessionTimeOut sessting or not.

**Update**
I just found out that [StructClear() does not end the session](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1846-Clearing-The-Session-Scope-Does-Not-End-Your-ColdFusion-Session.htm). So I guess I should just expire the cookies.

Comment: You'll want to use StructClear(session) not StructDelete.  StructDelete is for removing a single key from the structure.

Comment: Sean, while you are right, structClear() does not end the session. I just found this out a second ago. http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1846-Clearing-The-Session-Scope-Does-Not-End-Your-ColdFusion-Session.htm

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't suggesting that it would (hence my use of a comment instead of an answer), I just wanted to point out that your original code example would fail if left as it was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As usual, Ben Nadel has already blogged the answer...

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1847-Explicitly-Ending-A-ColdFusion-Session.htm

There are a few options, some quite safe, others use hidden methods that aren't guaranteed to be around in future version of ColdFusion or other CFML engines.  You might spot that I get a mention in his post since I love messing about with those hidden methods.  But if you want to do things properly (more future proof / engine switch proof), I'd suggest Ben's alternative methods.

*Edit*

Almost forgot, I created a function to stop the current session using another method (not mentioning in Ben Nadel's blog post).  It's still an undocumented feature, but is an improvement as it stops the session instantly, instead of setting it to 1 second to time out.

http://misterdai.wordpress.com/2010/06/15/cf-sessionstop-ending-a-cf-session/

**Further Edit**

Just explaining the different methods briefly, in case the linked sites ever disapppear.

To summarise the ways to stop a session in it's tracks...

1. Set the sessionTimeout to a value of 1 second.

   - Flag the targetted session (e.g. session.remove = true)
   - Detect and set low timeout (application.cfc)
     `if (StructKeyExists(session, 'remove') And aession.remove) {
     this.sessionTimeout = CreateTimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1);
     }`
   - Remove the association between the client and the sesssion by deleting the CFID / CFTOKEN cookies.
2. Similar to above but using session.setMaxInactiveInterval(1)

   - Undocumented, works but could change without notice between versions.
   - More flexible, doesn't have to have code within the application.cfc file.
   - Still have to remove cookies.
3. Force ColdFusion to remove the session instantly.

   - More use of undocumented features that could break between versions.
   - Can be used anywhere, don't have to worry about cookies or single second timeouts.

Code for approach 3...

```
<cffunction name="sessionStop" output="false">
  <cfset var local = StructNew() />
  <cfif Not StructKeyExists(application, 'applicationName')>
    <cfthrow message="Application.applicationName is missing." />
  </cfif>
  <cftry>
    <cfset local.sid = session.cfid & '_' & session.cftoken />
    <cfset local.jTracker = CreateObject('java', 'coldfusion.runtime.SessionTracker') />
    <cfset local.jTracker.cleanUp(application.applicationName, local.sid) />
    <cfcatch type="any">
      <cfthrow message="Error stopping session, may not exist." />
    </cfcatch>
  </cftry>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: I did! I was actually reading that blog post too when you posted the answer. Good stuff! Cheers!

Comment: When Mr. Nadel's blog goes away or changes it's directory structure, this answer will have no value. How about at least summarizing the answer?

Comment: Good point Al, I've updated with a brief description to the approaches.  Should be enough for people to work out the code needed :)

Comment: @MisterDai Nice one! by the way : http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html

Comment: What happens when you get an error that the cleanUp() method cannot be found?  This works great on my old server but not on the new one.  Is there a setting I need to enable?

Comment: @ConnieDeCinko you're new one may be using a newer version of ColdFusion.  There's no guarantee that internal method is available anymore.  Looks like CF10 added a SessionInvalidate() function that would do the same trick: https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/sessioninvalidate.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want to use structClear(). If I remember correctly, there are issues if the CFID and CFTOKEN keys get deleted from the SESSION struct. Here is the code we use to end a session:

```
<!--- Delete the session --->
<cfloop collection="#session#" item="skey">
    <cfif NOT listFindNoCase("cfid,cftoken,sessionid,urltoken", skey)>
        <cfset structDelete(session, skey) />
    </cfif>
</cfloop> 

<!--- Expire the CFID and CFTOKEN cookies to start a new session --->
<cfcookie name="cfid" expires="Now" />
<cfcookie name="cftoken" expires="Now" />

<!--- Expire the JSESSIONID cookie - only needed if J2EE sessions are used --->
<cfcookie name="jsessionid" expires="Now" />
```

So we delete all the keys from the SESSION except for CFID, CFTOKEN, SESSIONID, and URLTOKEN, then we expire the cookies that identify the session. When this happens CF should create new cookies and start a new session.